# localhost connection problem while using StartMeshcat

Tags: drake

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS via WSL and working on Python 3.10 on Visual Studio Code using the Remote - WSL extension.

When I import and run `StartMeshcat()` it successfully displays 'INFO:drake:Meshcat listening for connections at http://localhost:7000' but I can't reach my localhost, it gives the 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' error on any browser. I tried the generic solutions available on web regarding wsl localhost connection problems but none of them worked. What may be the cause? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you fix this issue??